# Exclude database from being in AlwaysOn Group

Tags: alwayson

Can I create a database on a primary server (such as a dba respository db) that is not a part of the AlwaysOn Group?  Therefore it will only reside on the primary and not be on the secondary replica.  Just create database and that's it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create database in primary server that is not part of AlwaysOn group. You can do the same in secondary as well. You can create database in any server and adding it to AlwaysOn is completely your choice. Hope this helps and let me know if any questions.